# Displaying django DateTimeRangeField() in form as separate inputs

Tags: django, forms, postgresql, datetime

I have a model like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    slot = DateTimeRangeField()
```

and the form as:

```
class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'slot',]
```

The form renders with 2 inputs for the lower and upper bounds of the date range. How can I render them as 4 inputs in the template? (lower date, lower time, upper date, upper time). Is there a widget that can do this?

Comment: I could use this to unpack a datetime object but I have a DateTimeRangeField which can't be split using SplitDateTimeWidget.

Answer (score 1):

found out I can do it like this:

```
widgets = { 'slot': RangeWidget(SplitDateTimeWidget()) }
```